# Prove that the solution of a system is the same as minimum of the sum of squares

Tags: optimization

I was reading through some results on google to learn simple optimization problems in MATLAB, and found a PDF where a method is described which I don't understand.

Here is a picture of it, or see [PDF](http://www.math.ksu.edu/math222/spring-2012/RootFindingMATLAB.pdf) page 5, Part III.

Why is the solution of the system equivalent to finding the minimum of the sum of the squares of the left hand sides?

[image: Description]

Thank you!!

Comment: how would you solve this?

Comment: by Mathematica i have got $4.30301*10^-29, {x -> 3.00205, y -> 3.99846}$

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, let's label the functions in the system:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x,y) &=& 3y + 0.005y\,\sin(5x) - 4x &=& 0\\
g(x,y) &=& x^2 + y^2 - 25 &=& 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

So we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Theta(x,y) &=& [f(x,y)]^2 + [g(x,y)]^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, $f(x,y)=0$ is a, slightly bent, line through the origin, and $g(x,y)=0$ is a circle centred at the origin. That geometry shows that these curves intersect, so there *is* a solution to the system.

It's obvious that $\Theta(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $f(x,y) = 0$ and $g(x,y) = 0$. Therefore, if we can find $(x_0,y_0)$, say, such that $\Theta(x_0,y_0) = 0$ then $(x_0,y_0)$ is a solution to the system.

Because $\Theta(x,y)$ is the sum of squares, it can't be negative, but we know from the above that it can be $0$. So minimising it is the same as solving $\Theta(x,y) = 0$. In other words, minimising $\Theta(x,y)$ is the same as solving the system.